# Play Framework compile giving warnings, how to view them?

Tags: scala, playframework

How do I see the warnings created during running `compile` on my Play app from the console?

```
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 13 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to C:\...\target\scala-2.10\classes...
[warn] there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
[warn] one warning found
[success] Total time: 13 s, completed 13-Feb-2014 00:43:23
```

I tried running `clean` then `compile -feature` but that just threw errors.

I'm using:

```
       _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |
|  __/|_|\____|\__ /
|_|            |__/

play 2.2.1 built with Scala 2.10.2 (running Java 1.7.0_51), http://www.playframework.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a note, this is a little bit different from a standard warning (which will show up just fine by default).

There's a feature warning happening in the scala compiler; that's where that "there were 1 feature warning(s)" message comes from.

You need to pass -feature into scalac as part of scalacOptions which can be done by adding something like the following to your Build.scala:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  scalacOptions += "-feature"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Play 2.2.1, you should be using the new build.sbt format and writing your config as follows:

```
name := "your-project-name"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"
```

Then add your library dependencies

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.26",
  "org.bouncycastle" % "bcprov-jdk15on" % "1.49",
  "net.iharder" % "base64" % "2.3.8",
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.3"
)
```

Then add any compiler flags.  I typically add most of these while developing because they enable certain checks and language features that are worth having.

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-encoding",
  "UTF-8",
  "-deprecation",
  "-unchecked",
  "-feature",
  "-language:postfixOps",
  "-language:implicitConversions"
)

play.Project.playScalaSettings
```